# spring boot --spring.application.json parameters not being set

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that currently has a "mysql" profile that sets the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url = 
spring.datasource.username = 
spring.datasource.password =
```

in /resources/application-mysql.properties file.
This is working great. When I run the mysql profile it connects to the local mysql database. When I don't run the mysql profile it uses the default h2 database. Next I want to get rid of the application.my-sql.properties and pass those values in via the command line. From the documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) I would expect something like the following to work. But strangely, it never gets these properties and runs the h2 database instead.

```
   java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.application.json='{"spring": {"datasource": {"url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "username":"user","password":"pw"}}}'
```

Comment: Did you also try as system argument? -Dspring.application.json=

Comment: I ended up going with active profile instead. java -Dspring.profiles.active=myprofile -jar myapp.jar

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this does work. As Vaelyr pointed out in the comments, setting it as system argument worked:

```
-Dspring.application.json='{"spring":{"datasource":{"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}}}'
```